# Change Button Color based Comparison Modal Input Value And Target Input Value

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, operator-keyword

I tried to google around to find a way to change button colour for below case:

Let’s say I have an onclick Button where I click and it opens a modal box which contains an Input box and a Submit Button.

1. If I input “90” in the Input box and submit it It will compare with
   my target value “100”
2. If I input a value less than the target Value the onclick Button will
   turn red and its text will change to “90”
3. If I input a value greater than the target Value, the onclick Button 
   will turn green and its text will change to “90”

Please help ! Any idea will help.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Set event listener `submit` that grabs the element through `document.getElementById` or `document.getElementsByClassName` and changes `background-color` CSS attribute

Comment: I use the method below but somehow it is not working. I'm not sure where i did wrong. Can you please help ? 

Link : https://jsfiddle.net/ck08rx2m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById('b1');
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
// Arithematic Operator Control
var target_value = document.getElementById('inputtarget');
function checkValue(){ 
  var inputvalue = document.getElementById('modal1');
  var buttonsubmit = document.getElementById('b1');
  var value = parseInt(inputvalue.value);
  var targetValue = parseInt(target_value.value);
 
  if (value < targetValue){
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'red' ;
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value ; 
  }
  else if (value > targetValue){
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'green';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value ; 
  }
  else{
    buttonsubmit.style.background = '';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = '1'; 
  }
  modal.style.display = "none";
  return false;
}
```

```css
#inputtarget {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1;
  }
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
}
#modal1 {
  height:70px;
  width:100px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Button and Target Value -->
<div>
<button id="b1" onclick="return checkValue()">1</button>
<input id="inputtarget" type="number" ondrop="returnfalse;" onpaste="returnfalse;" 
           onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57';><br>
</div>  

<!-- The Modal Box -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>PLEASE INPUT QUANTITY</p>
    <input id=modal1 type="number" ondrop="returnfalse;" onpaste="returnfalse;" 
           onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57'; 
           style=font-size:20px><br>
    <br>
    <button id="submit" onclick="return checkValue()">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

here the same code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ck08rx2m/16/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But i have problem with my code. I could not submit it to work

Below is my link
https://jsfiddle.net/ck08rx2m/

Comment: is not clear which button had to get the style, is the button in the modal?

Comment: the "1" button , not "submit" button. "Submit" button is to trigger the values comparison.

Comment: this is so good ! 
How do i close Modal using "Submit" button ? 
I used data-dismiss("Modal") , doesn't seems to work.

Comment: look my last  change, so you use modal.style.display = "block"; to open the modal then to close is natural to think to use modal.style.display = "none";
I do not know where did you take data-dismiss("Modal")

Comment: something mess up after you added the modal.style.display and deleted "parseInt". Now it only show "green" even the value < targetValue

Comment: if you click RUN CODE SNIPPET it still works, I might miss something,
BTW remove parseInt was a mistake, that is needed

Comment: I did, 
let's say my target is 10, so 9 turn button red and 11 turn button green. but it always green now.

Comment: my snippets still works even with your mentioned example, 
are you sure you copied everything? di you try to run my snippets here in stackoverflow?it works also in https://jsfiddle.net/ck08rx2m/16/

Comment: it is working after parseInt added. Thank you for your help. it certainly help me alot

Comment: if this solve your problem please mark it as solved and if you like vote up.
PS keep coding and enjoy JS :)

Comment: Hi, I have a quick question? 
Now that i only working on One Button toward One Modal and one checkvalue. Seems pretty pleasant. 
If i have two or more buttons toward one modal and one checkvalue. How do i code differently ?

Comment: not sure I get you, I would not mixup a new question with the current  one even if related. I suggest to put a new question with the new html markup, you can tag me for help.
Btw should be pretty similar, would be nice you try by yourself following what you learnt in this post and after if you still need help make a new post with the new problem